# Overcoming MaxNodeCount > 100 limit in BreezeJS

Tags: javascript, breeze

For testing purposes I'm querying the term 'test' within a table on several columns. The filter url generated looks like this:

> $filter=(substringof('test',Column1) eq true)) and
>   (substringof('test',Column2) eq true)) and
>   (substringof('test',Column3) eq true)) ...

The query works fine until the number of columns queried exceeds 15. At this point I get the following error message:

> Query failed: The node count limit of '100' has been exceeded. To
>   increase the limit, set the 'MaxNodeCount' property on
>   QueryableAttribute or ODataValidationSettings.

I got around it by adding the following attribute to the api method being called:

```
[Queryable(
    AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All,
    AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions,
    MaxNodeCount = 200)]
```

But this does not seem to play well with foreign entities. They are always null when using the expand function. I checked the resulting filter url and it does include the necessary $expand syntax.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

update your controller method with this attribute:

[EnableBreezeQuery(  MaxNodeCount = 200)]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure $expand works when there is no MaxNodeCount set?

If you use WebAPI, $expand won't do anything for you, you will have response from server like:

```
SelectedSubItem=null
```

Instead, try going into your model and instead of returning

```
return Context.MyClass;
```

do this:

```
return Context.MyClass.Include("SelectedSubItem");
```